# Relatório em PHP com quebra de seção

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma consulta em MySQL que me retorna várias linhas de resumos de vendas agrupados por vendedor. Cada vendedor é de uma cidade. Como insiro um sub-total ao final de cada cidade? Uso PDO para abstração.

A instrução é essa:

```
SELECT rpaautonomos.autonomo, MASK(rpaautonomos.cpf, '###.###.###-##') AS cpf, MASK(rpaautonomos.inss, '###.###.####-#') AS inss, DATE_FORMAT (rpaautonomos.nascimento,'%d/%m/%Y') AS nascimento, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT((SUM(rparecibos.valor) + SUM(rparetencoes.retido)), 2, 'de_DE')) AS bruto_mensal, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(SUM(rparetencoes.inss), 2, 'de_DE')) AS inss_mensal, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(SUM(rparetencoes.irf), 2, 'de_DE')) AS irf_mensal, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(SUM(rparetencoes.iss), 2, 'de_DE')) AS iss_mensal, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(SUM(rparetencoes.retido), 2, 'de_DE')) AS retido_mensal, CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(SUM(rparecibos.valor), 2, 'de_DE')) AS valor_mensal FROM rparecibos INNER JOIN rpaautonomos ON rparecibos.cpf = rpaautonomos.cpf INNER JOIN rparetencoes ON rparecibos.chave = rparetencoes.chave WHERE MONTH(rparecibos.emissao) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY rpaautonomos.autonomo ORDER BY rpaautonomos.autonomo ASC
```

Comment: O que?? Poderia esclarecer a pergunta.

Comment: Precisava de inserir um subtotal ao final de cada autônomo no relatório, e estava tentando fazer via SQL mas achei uma solução pelo PHP.

Comment: Quer denunciar um comportamento injusto adotado pelos usuários do site use o canal de comunicação competente que é [meta] onde são discutidos o funcionamento e as políticas do Stack Overflow em Português em vez de discutir o programação em si, seja franco e abra uma discussão expondo o problema apontando os responsáveis e as provas. Não use o campo de comentários para ventilar acusações genérica, esse só deve ser usado para realizar orientações e esclarecimentos a respeito das publicações.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fiz em PHP da forma abaixo e deu certo...

```html
if ($relatorio) {
    foreach ($relatorio as $row) {
        [...]
        $bruto_mensal += $row["bruto_mensal"];
        $inss_mensal += $row["inss_mensal"];
    }
    $tg_bruto_mensal = number_format($bruto_mensal, 2, ",", ".");
    $tg_inss_mensal = number_format($inss_mensal, 2, ",", ".");
}
```